# Trying to throw Exceptions in method called in an ActionListener

Tags: java, bluej

So I am unsure why I am getting an error when trying to call a method with an action listener for a button. I created the panel and set the layout to flow layout, and then added it to the content pane, and then created the button here...

```
JButton buyButton = new JButton("Buy");
    panel.add(buyButton);
    buyButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {buy();}});
```

I then created a try catch block in the buy method...

```
public void buy throws OverException
{
    try{
       //tries the code
    }
    catch(OverException e){
      //does stuff...
    }
}
```

But it keeps saying that it must be caught or declared to be thrown in the method calling of buy() when creating the button.

Answer (score 1):

So do what the compiler is clearly telling you to do: `... must be caught or declared to be thrown in the method calling of buy()`.

`OverException` has to be caught in `actionPerformed` or `actionPerformed` has to be declared to throw `OverException`.

You can't change the declaration of `actionPerformed`, so make it catch the exception:

```
buyButton.addActionListener(
    new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                try {
                    buy();
                }
                catch(OverException ex)
                {
                     // TODO error handling
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have added new ActionListener() as an inner class and the implementing method is actionPerformed(). You are calling buy() inside actionPerformed().You except your code can spit "OVerException".  So you can handle this exception in 2 ways:

- catch the exception inside the code itself.You did it.
- throw the exception to the calling method so some where else it would be handled.You did that with this.`public void buy throws OverException`.But the calling method(actionPerformed()) didnt handle it. So you got the compilation error

way 1:

```
buyButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {buy();}});

public void buy() 
{
try{
   //tries the code
}
catch(OverException e){
  //does stuff...
}
}
```

way 2 was suggested by @john3136